# Clone/Copy SQL Server database daily?

Tags: c#, sql-server, synchronization, restore, job-scheduling

I have a SQL Server database where I process some data using a .Net application. The processing takes quite some time and its basically pulling down data from a service/api and stores it in this database of mine.

However.. I need to keep the data in the database synced with the data fetched from the service/api. So I was thinking that maybe I could have two databases.

The idea:

1. `Database1` is always cleared by my .Net application and then I simply pull down all the data from the service/api again and re-builds the data. This is done daily. (This usually takes about 4.5 hours).
2. After 6 hours I copy/restore all the data from `Database1` to `Database2`
3. My data-consuming app/frontend consumes the data in `Database2`

This way I would not have the need of "syncing" data in a single database.
However.. Im not sure of how to set a daily restore in SQL Server, any ideas of how to do this?

Also.. sorry if this might be the wrong forum for db-questions..

Br,
Inx

Comment: You could use one of the types of [SQL Server Replication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152531.aspx)?

Comment: As an SQL replication question, this may be more on-topic at ServerFault...

Comment: You could have a look at the **AlwaysOn** feature in SQL Server 2012, that allows you to have a "light-weight" replication, and the replicas (the "copies") can be used for e.g. reporting etc.

Comment: Thanks, a Snapshot replication was exactly what I was looking for :)